# Como puedo ajustar este carrusel vertical al 100% de alto y un 20% de ancho de una pantalla

Tags: javascript, html, css

1. como puedo hacer que un slide vertical ocupe el 100% de alto de mi
   pantalla
2. Que solo me muestre 3 imágenes en pantalla, pero que pueda poner mas y las oculte
3. Que tenga un autoplay

Aquí les dejo un ejemplo:
[image: ejemplo del carrusel vertical]

el problema que me sale que si meten imágenes muy grandes las pone al tamaño original y no me respeta el que se le asigne a al contenedor del slider y ademas se sale del tamaño del monitor al **heigh:100vh;**

No sé como hacer que se ajuste al 100%

Lo que llevo hasta aquí es que si funciona, no se en donde pueda subir mi proyecto completo para que lo puedan ver

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

*,
*:after,
*:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}


/* Elastislide Style */

.elastislide-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: none;
  height: 100vh;
}

.no-js .elastislide-list {
  display: block;
}

.elastislide-carousel ul li {
  min-width: 20px;
}

.elastislide-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 60px;
}

.elastislide-wrapper.elastislide-loading {
  background-image: url(../images/loading.gif);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}

.elastislide-vertical {
  padding: 0;
}

.elastislide-carousel {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.elastislide-carousel ul {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
  -moz-transform: translateX(0px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(0px);
  -o-transform: translateX(0px);
  transform: translateX(0px);
}

.elastislide-carousel ul li {
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.elastislide-vertical ul li {
  display: block;
}

.elastislide-carousel ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.elastislide-carousel ul li a img {
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid white;
}


/* Navigation Arrows */

.elastislide-wrapper nav span {
  position: absolute;
  background: red url(../images/nav.png) no-repeat 4px 3px;
  width: 23px;
  height: 23px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-indent: -9000px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.elastislide-wrapper nav span:hover {
  opacity: 1.0
}

.elastislide-vertical nav span {
  top: 30%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -11px;
  background-position: -17px 5px;
}

.elastislide-vertical nav span.elastislide-next {
  bottom: 30%;
  top: auto;
  background-position: -17px -18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor-slide-vertical">
  <!-- Elastislide Carousel -->
  <ul id="carousel" class="elastislide-list">
    <li>
      <a href="#"><img src="images/a-01.png" alt="a01"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#"><img src="images/a-02.png" alt="a02"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#"><img src="images/a-03.png" alt="a03"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#"><img src="images/a-04.png" alt="a04"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#"><img src="images/a-05.png" alt="a05"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <!-- End Elastislide Carousel -->
</div>
```

**Dejo la liga la proyecto para que lo puedan ver en su navegador**
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LILl3sqgiMmH9-U1Odj_9GXx98cym9HM/view?usp=sharing

el codigo original es de

> Elastislide en codrops

Comment: solo cambiale el tamaño de la imagen `height: 33vh;` pueba en `.elastislide-carousel ul li a img` por la linia 75

Comment: ohhhhhhhhhhh muchas gracias por la ayuda, muchas, muchas gracias. Excelente, me sirvió súper bien.